# Como ordenar 3 funciones en orden de ejecución

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

En mi codigo hay una `form` que recoge un valor que ingresa el usuario llamado `name`. Al enviar esta `form` se ejecuta una función (`addMarkUp()`) que añade lo que sea que es `name` al `state` del componente. Después de esto hay otra función (`updateDynamo()`) que con la información recientemente añadida al `state`, envía estos datos a una base de datos.

```js
export default class AddSite extends Component {
    state = {
        new_location: "",
        new_site: "",
        view_location: [42.600273, -5.572582],
        user_sites: [],
        zoom: 2,
        current_user: ""
    }

    updateDynamo = () => {
        axios.patch(`${apiGatewayDevStage}/add-site`, {
            email: this.state.current_user,
            sites: this.state.user_sites,
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log('DB en Dynamo actualizada')
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))

    }
    addMarkUp = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let itemsCounter = this.state.user_sites.length + 1; 
        const newSite = this.state.new_site;
        Geocode.fromAddress(newSite).then(
            response => {
                const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    user_sites: [{ 
                        "name": newSite, "id": itemsCounter, coordinates: [lat, lng] 
                            }, ...prevState.user_sites]
                }))
                this.updateDynamo()
            },
            error => { console.error(error); }
        );
    }
    async deleteSite(id) {
        await this.setState({
            user_sites: this.state.user_sites.filter(function (item) {
                return item.id !== id
            })
        })
        this.updateDynamo()
    }
    // Conversor nombre a coordenadas
    geoCodeToCoordinates = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const newAdress = this.state.new_location;
        Geocode.fromAddress(newAdress).then(
            response => {
                const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                this.setState({
                    view_location: [lat, lng],
                    zoom: 6
                })
            },
            error => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
    }
     // recoger datos en la form al state
    onChangeNewLocation = event => {
        this.setState({
            new_location: event.target.value
        })
    };
    onChangeNewSite = event => {
        this.setState({
            new_site: event.target.value
        })
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="addsite-container">
                <Container>
          
                        {/** AÑADIDOR SITIOS */}
                        <Col className="p-0">
                            <Container className="add-container">
                                <Form onSubmit={this.addMarkUp}>
                                    <h4>Añade un sitio </h4>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Form.Control type="text" onChange={this.onChangeNewSite} value={this.state.new_site} placeholder="ejemplo: Madrid, New York...etc" />
                                    </Row>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Button type="submit" variant="success">Añadir</Button>
                                    </Row>

                                </Form>
                            </Container>
                            <ListGroup>
                                {this.state.user_sites.map((site, i) => (
                                    <div key={i} className="added-items-container">
                                        <ListGroup.Item className="added-items" variant="warning" >{site.name}</ListGroup.Item>
                                        <Button onClick={this.deleteSite.bind(this, site.id)}>Quitar</Button>
                                    </div>
                                ))}

                            </ListGroup>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>

                </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Pero he tenido que añadir otra función más (`insertPicture()`) porque necesito que se busque una foto online relacionada con el `name`que se ha recogido en la `form`. Necesito tener la respuesta de esta función, que conecta con una API de fotos online, para que cuando `addMarkUp()` se ejecute, también tenga disponible el valor `url` correspondiente al `name` para añadirlo al state.

```js
insertPicture(site) {
        pexelsClient.search(site, 1, 1)
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                console.err(e);
            });
    }
```

Es decir, pienso que para hacer funcionar esto necesitaría tener el siguiente order de ejecución:

1 Primero: `insertPicture()`
2 Segundo: `addMarkUp()`
3 Tercero: `updateDynamo()`

El problema es que he probado a hacerlo de la siguiente manera y parece que no es la apropiada:

```js
addMarkUp = (async event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let itemsCounter = this.state.user_sites.length + 1; 
        const newSite = this.state.new_site;
        // Primero ejecutar esta función:
        await insertPicture(this.state.new_site);
        Geocode.fromAddress(newSite).then(
            response => {
                const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    user_sites: [{ 
                        "name": newSite, "id": itemsCounter, coordinates: [lat, lng] 
                            }, ...prevState.user_sites]
                }))
                this.updateDynamo()
            },
            error => { console.error(error); }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias formas de afrontar el reto que propones, y aunque, en mi opinión no sería el sitio idóneo de hacer esa lógica en la vist, voy a tratar de ofrecerte una solución al problema que comentas.

Cuando llamas a `insertPicture` no esperas la respuesta para, entiendo que si necesitas los datos de esa llamada para realizar la siguiente, así debería ser, así podemos devolver una promesa en ese método.

insertPicture quedaría así:

```js
insertPicture = async (site) => { // Sin bind en una clase
   return pexelsClient.search(site, 1, 1)        
}
```

Ahora en `addMarkup` donde tienes el await SI te funcionará porque el método ahora devuelve una promesa ( no olvides añadir `async` al método `addMarkup`)

```js
const pictureData = await insertPicture(this.state.new_site);
```

y para el resto de las funciones dependientes haría lo mismo, espero te sirva

Error al añadir una ciudad:

el problema es que estás haciendo uso del `this` pero ahí no tiene la referencia de la clase.

cambia

```js
addMarkUp(event) {
```

por

```js
addMarkUp = async (event) => {
```

y ya lo tienes
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-lake-mi4cp

Comment: No me deja poner funciones asyincronas usando arrow function, por qué puede ser? Lo he probado haciendo con funciones normales, y me sale el mismo error que ayer. Cuando el código llega a "const pictureData = await insertPicture(this.state.new_site);" salta que (this.state.new_site) es undefined. Básicamente si le quito la arrow funcion y la haga función normal, this.state.new_site salta como undefined. Pero si le pongo la arrow function no me deja ponerle el async

Comment: ¿Puedes montar un sandbox con ejemplo reproducible?

Comment: Si, aquí te lo paso: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-sound-jks3v Da algun fallo en la compilación pero si cierras el aviso que sale al cargar, la app funciona. Básicamente es poner una ciudad en la form de la derecha ("Añade un sitio") y pulsar Añadir. Aquí es dónde se rompe si le pongo el arrow function.

Comment: Perfect, voy a verlo

Comment: No sé si ves mis cambios en el tuyo, pero se te rompe porque estás utilizando el `.then` dentro de `insertPicture`, prueba a ponerlo como en el ejemplo, aparte de que el mapa se ve entrecortado parece que funciona bien. te dejo el link con eso actualizado: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-lake-mi4cp

Comment: Ya, está perdona te habia entendido mal, actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: Vaya, entonces era yo que no me acordaba de poner bien el async en las funciones arrow ! milGracias

Comment: Recuerda que si usas métodos dentro de las clases en React tienes que hacer 2 cosas, lo óptimo según la documentación oficial es crear `binds` en el constructor, la otra alternativa es usar arrow funcs, me alegra haberte podido ayudar, un placer!